# user interface guidelines for a website targeting kids

Tags: user-interface, web, usability

We are planning to design a website for evaluating kids (games, quiz). Are there any specific user interface guidelines for targeting the kids (e.g. keyboard usage in a laptop or a standalone keyboard, ability to control a mouse, ability to navigate the user interface and its controls, size of buttons, page navigation)? We are looking for things which we need to be careful about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jakob Nielsen has a pretty decent Alert Box about [usability for children](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/children.html). There's also a [usability guide](http://www.nngroup.com/reports/kids/) at the end of the alert box. In summary: kids don't scroll, they like reading, are suckers for advertising, and if [Microsoft Bob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Bob) was marketed to children, it would've been a hit.